# What is the difference between a double infinite series and the Cauchy Product?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-product

Let's say we have the double infinite series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty a_n b_m$ which is absolutely convergent. Furthermore, the two series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ are absolutely convergent.

I know the Cauchy Product is: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{i=2}^n a_i b_{n-i} = \left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n\right) \left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n\right)$

**1**) However, is it also true that the double infinite series equals the Cauchy Product in the given scenario? I.e. that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty a_n b_m = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{i=2}^n a_i b_{n-i} = \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\right) \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\right)$$

**2**) In particular I am interested in: does the above (abs. convergent) double infinite series "split" into two (abs. convergent) infinite series? If yes, is this also true for general convergence?

**3**) I am thinking about doing this:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty a_n b_m = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty a_n b_m\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(a_n \sum_{m=1}^\infty b_m \right) = \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \right) \left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty b_m \right)$$

Is that correct?

Comment: In the expression for the Cauchy product, the $n$ sum needs to start at 2, not 1. Or you could have all sums start at 0.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. This is true whenever at least one of the series is absolutely convergent. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Convergence_and_Mertens%27_theorem).
2. You can interpret it that way. Absolute convergence implies that the order of summation or taking limits does not influence the result. This is not true for general convergence, where that order matters.
3. Yes. This is an algebraic manipulation where the last step requires absolute convergence (because you pull one limit out of the other).

Edit: You should let all the sums start at $0$ for the formulas to be correct.

Comment: Your point 3 isn't quite right. This algebraic manipulation is always valid (since the two series converge), absolute convergence is not required for these manipulations (it doesn't hurt of course, but it's not needed). All we're doing there is pulling one constant (namely $\sum b_m$) out of a series. Absolute convergence is only required for point 1, when claiming the product of series equals the Cauchy product.